# How to find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n+8^n}{11^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n+8^n}{11^n}$$

My textbook does not give any example to help solve problems like this, only geometric series and I do not believe this is a geometric series?

Comment: It's a sum of two geometric series.

Comment: You have to ask the Lord of Light.

Comment: RIP Stannis gone but never forgotten

Answer (score 10):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n+8^n}{11^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{11}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{8}{11}\right)^n$$